# Nvidia 530 (nvidia-driver-530)

Tags: nvidia, 23.04, usb-c

04 and the Nvidia 530 driver does not seem to be available in the additional driver's menu

I wondered when this will be available in the repos and if the update is worth waiting for.

The only reason I would like to update is I have my screen keeps randomly disconnecting (USB C to display port connection), I know it's unlikely to fix this issue but worth a shot.

Is there any change log from the 525 to 530 driver, I cant seem to find one online

Comment: I have installed Lubuntu just yesterday and all of the drivers old and new including the 530 one is in the additional driver menu. What version do you use ?

Comment: It looks like this driver has been posted to the repos for Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10, but not yet for 23.04.

Comment: I've just realized how messed up my original post was, Not sure what happened there. But your comment reminded me to check and it looks like it is now available on the menu, Im just installing it now.

Do we have some public changelog on the differences between the drivers?